# Adding "hidden (or meta)" column to DataTable that will not be displayed in the bound DataGridView

Tags: c#

I'm working on a DataGridView `dgv` in a Windows form. The `dgv` is bound to a DataTable `dt` as its datasource.

```
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

In order to efficiently locate a particular row, I need to have a `id (int)` column in `dt`. However, since an ID has no use to a user, I would like to *hide* the entire `id` column in the `dgv` so the user won't even know there is an `id` column. How should I do that? If that's not possible, is there any other work around? I'm using VS C# Express 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Visible property of your [DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.visible.aspx).

From msdn:

```
// Hide a band of cells. 
private void Button6_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    DataGridViewBand band = dataGridView.Rows[3];
    band.Visible = false;
}
```